# authorize the action in relation to the precedent action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I looking for a way to authorize a user to access an action only if he come from a specific action. I thought of Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath, but that doesn t sound very secure.Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: Are you able to store cookies?

Comment: I don t handle cookies for the moment.